# Controller works in preview but not in org

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I have a Visualforce page that incorporates an app and a component. When I try the VFpage in preview, everything works. But not in Sales cloud when i connect the initialising VF-page to a 'List Button' and tie that button to the Account object. What is displayed when pressed is the search field, as it should. But no logic is applied (No queries made). So probably there is some parameter that i have not set. I would be very glad if I could get some help with finding it. 
Thanks in advance.

Here is the VF-Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="Accounts">
<apex:includeLightning />
<div id="lightning" />
<script>
    $Lightning.use("c:AddCreatorsContainer", function() {
      $Lightning.createComponent("c:AddCampaignCreatorsToCampaign",
          {},
          "lightning",
          function(cmp) {
            console.log("Component was created");
          }
      );
    });
</script>
```

App (Small class just to wrap the important component below)

```
<aura:application access="global" extends="ltng:outApp">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:AddCampaignCreatorsToCampaign"/>
</aura:application>
```

AddCampaignCreatorsToCampaign.cmp (It's a component)

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" controller="AddCmpgnToCreatorsSearchController">
<aura:attribute name="objectName" type="String" default="Account"/>
<aura:attribute name="fieldName" type="String" default="Name"/>
<aura:attribute name="selectRecordId" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="selectRecordName" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="Label" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="searchRecords" type="List"/>
<aura:attribute name="required" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
<aura:attribute name="iconName" type="String" default="action:new_account"/>
<aura:attribute name="LoadingText" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
<aura:attribute name="AccountList" type="List"/>
<div>
    <div class="slds-form-element">

        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <div class="slds-combobox_container">

                <div class="slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click" aura:id="resultBox" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox">
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_left-right" role="none">

                        <aura:if isTrue="{!!empty(v.selectRecordId)}">
                            <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-search slds-input__icon iconheight">
                                <lightning:icon class="slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_small slds-icon-text-default" iconName="{!v.iconName}" size="x-small" alternativeText="icon" />
                            </span> 
                        </aura:if>
                        <lightning:input required="{!v.required}" aura:id="userinput" label="{!v.Label}" name="searchText" onchange="{!c.searchField}" value="{!v.selectRecordName}" class="leftspace"/> 
                        <aura:if isTrue="{!empty(v.selectRecordId)}">
                            <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-search slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right iconheight">
                                <lightning:icon class="slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_small slds-icon-text-default" iconName="utility:search" size="x-small" alternativeText="icon" />
                            </span> 
                            <aura:set attribute="else">
                                <button class="slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right slds-button slds-button_icon iconheight" onclick="{!c.resetData}">
                                    <lightning:icon class="slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_small slds-icon-text-default" iconName="utility:clear" size="x-small" alternativeText="icon" />
                                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Clear</span></button>
                            </aura:set>
                        </aura:if>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Second part display result -->
                    <div id="listbox-id-1" class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_length-with-icon-7 slds-dropdown_fluid" role="listbox">
                        <ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" role="presentation">
                            <aura:iteration items="{!v.searchRecords}" var="serecord" indexVar="hdtv">
                                <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">

                                    <div id="{!serecord.recId}" data-name="{!serecord.recName}" onclick="{!c.setSelectedRecord}" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_entity slds-listbox__option_has-meta" role="option">
                                        <span class="slds-media__figure">
                                            <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-account">
                                                <lightning:icon iconName="{!v.iconName}" class="slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_small slds-icon-text-default" size="x-small"/>
                                            </span>
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="slds-media__body">
                                            <span class="slds-listbox__option-text slds-listbox__option-text_entity">{!serecord.recName}</span>
                                            <span class="slds-listbox__option-meta slds-listbox__option-meta_entity">{!v.objectName} • {!serecord.recName}</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </aura:iteration>
                            <aura:if isTrue="{!and(v.searchRecords.length == 0 , !v.LoadingText)}">
                                No result found.
                            </aura:if>
                            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.LoadingText}">
                                Loading...
                            </aura:if>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

AddCmpgnToCreatorsSearchController.apxc

```
public class AddCmpgnToCreatorsSearchController {

@AuraEnabled
public static List<SObJectResult> getResults(String ObjectName, String fieldName, String value) {
    List<SObJectResult> sObjectResultList = new List<SObJectResult>();
    for(sObject so : Database.Query('Select Id,'+fieldName+' FROM '+ObjectName+' WHERE '+fieldName+' LIKE \'%' + value + '%\'')) {
        String fieldvalue = (String)so.get(fieldName);
        sObjectResultList.add(new SObjectResult(fieldvalue, so.Id));
    }

    return sObjectResultList;
}

public class SObJectResult {
    @AuraEnabled
    public String recName;
    @AuraEnabled
    public Id recId;

    public SObJectResult(String recNameTemp, Id recIdTemp) {
        recName = recNameTemp;
        recId = recIdTemp;
    }
}
```

}

AddCampaignCreatorsToCampaignController.js (The controller to AddCampaignCreatorsToCampaign.cmp)

```
({
searchField : function(component, event, helper) {
    var currentText = event.getSource().get("v.value");
    var resultBox = component.find('resultBox');
    component.set("v.LoadingText", true);
    if(currentText.length > 0) {
        $A.util.addClass(resultBox, 'slds-is-open');
    }
    else {
        $A.util.removeClass(resultBox, 'slds-is-open');
    }
    var action = component.get("c.getResults");
    action.setParams({
        "ObjectName" : component.get("v.objectName"),
        "fieldName" : component.get("v.fieldName"),
        "value" : currentText
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var STATE = response.getState();
        if(STATE === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.searchRecords", response.getReturnValue());
            if(component.get("v.searchRecords").length == 0) {
                console.log('000000');
            }
        }
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
            var errors = response.getError();
            if (errors) {
                if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                    console.log("Error message: " + 
                                errors[0].message);
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Unknown error");
            }
        }
        component.set("v.LoadingText", false);
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

setSelectedRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
    var currentText = event.currentTarget.id;
    var resultBox = component.find('resultBox');
    $A.util.removeClass(resultBox, 'slds-is-open');
    //component.set("v.selectRecordName", currentText);
    component.set("v.selectRecordName", event.currentTarget.dataset.name);
    component.set("v.selectRecordId", currentText);
    component.find('userinput').set("v.readonly", true);
}, 

resetData : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.selectRecordName", "");
    component.set("v.selectRecordId", "");
    component.find('userinput').set("v.readonly", false);
}
})
```

(I have 2 controllers for the component as can be seen. One .js and one .apxc)

Comment: What do you mean when you say "no logic is applied"? Could you [edit] the body of your question to be very specific about the expected behavior and what you actually observe?

Comment: The code is here to serve as a searchfield. The field itself is displayed. In Preview there is also searchqueries flowing whenever input in this field happens. These queries disappear when the code is live within its environment in the org.

Comment: Bump. I'd gladly take any general pointers or anything since I'm still stuck with this.

Comment: Solved this. Everything WAS working. The lightning element was extremely small (thin) though so the results remained hidden in a scrollbar. On mac these scrollbars are also hidden when not active so I had no way of knowing what was going on. I added: 
  <div class="slds-form-element" name="divHeight" type="Integer" default="100">
  The attributes divheight and its 100 value and now everything is displayed correctly. Maybe this helps someone. Out.